# Is it possible that the acceleration of the growth of our universe is driven by the overall gravitational pull of neighboring universes

Tags: gravity, cosmology, acceleration, universe, multiverse

I am painfully unequipped when I think about my my knowledge of physics. Still, I am enthralled, as many of us are, by the mysteries and complexity of the universe, both known and unknown.

I was thinking today that the entire universe must itself exhibit some overall gravitational effect. If we take the multiverse as a given, then, where there are infinite numbers of universes existing alongside ours in sort of web (some "mother" universe), then is it plausible that the acceleration of the expansion of our universe is due in part to the pull from those universes that surround our own? Perhaps they are larger than ours and thus exhibit a much greater force.

I'm not expecting this to be considered even a remotely sound proposition, but I wanted to throw the idea out there and see what others had to say. I'm hoping, even, to learn a thing or two.

Thanks for reading if you even decided to go this far!